# Request a React component to take action other than render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wish to send a message to a React component to request it do something other than re-render.

Specifically, I wish to request a component containing a grid to save the grid data.

I know that I can send data into a component via props and that change of state will trigger re-rendering.

However, how can I pass an event rather than data into the component?

The solution I am currently using is to use events: https://github.com/primus/EventEmitter3.  My concern with this approach is that it is not linked to the React lifecycle and as such, events might reach the component at an inappropriate stage in the component lifecycle.

Is there an idiomatic way that I can do this just using React?

Answer (score 0):

"However, how can I pass an event rather than data into the component?"

Not exactly sure what you mean. If I think I understand what you're trying to do, you can pass a function down to the lower component which gets fired off on the parent level:

```js
const Child = ({ handleChildClick }) => {
  const someData = { name: "John", age: 69 };
  // Where someData can either be from state or a variable (just using functional component as it's easier to read imo)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleChildClick(someData)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const childClicked = data => {
    console.log("Data from child: ", data);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Child handleChildClick={childClicked} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

So when the child's event is fired off

Comment: Sorry Mikey - I know I can pass a function from parent to child.  I want parent instead to ask the child to do something - such as save its data.